# Using Express.js and Puppeteer with multiple URL at the same time

Tags: node.js, express, puppeteer

I am having trouble using express.Router() and Puppeteer. When I tried to send data (which is the URL) to the Node.JS instance that was running on PM2 at the same time, they are returning the same value.

### Visual Sample:

### Browser: Google Chrome 64Bit Windows

Tab 1: https://api.domain.com/wp/01

Tab 2: https://api.domain.com/wp/02

Enter key was pressed at the same time to send the request

### Node Instance:

```
app.get("/:id/:video", function (req, res) {
  
  var id = req.params.id;
  var episode = req.params.episode;
  url = `www.domain2.com/${id}/${video}`;

  rs(url, (err, resp, html) => {
    
    (async () => {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: ["--no-sandbox"],
      });

      const page = await browser.newPage();

      await page.on("response", async (response) => {
        if (response.url().includes("api.php?id=")) {
          var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(await response.json()));

          var sourceOne = data.source.filter(function (el) {
            return el.label == "devVideo";
          });

        

            if (one != "") {
              return res.status(200).json({
                link: sourceOne[0].file,
              });
            } 
          }
        }
      });

      // console.log(object.response);
      await page.goto(url, {
        waitUntil: "networkidle0",
        // Remove the timeout
        timeout: 0,
      });

      await page.close();
      await browser.close();
    })();
  });
});
```

The url that has been sent from browser to nodejs was processed

### Result

**Expected Results:**

**Tab 1**: https://domain2.com/1.mp4
**Tab 2**: https://domain2.com/2.mp4


**Got Results:**

**Tab 1**: https://domain2.com/1.mp4
**Tab 2**: https://domain2.com/1.mp4

As you can see on the 'Got Results', the results are the same. Now I'm confused...

Comment: `await page.on("response", async (response) => {` doesn't make sense. `.on` registers an event handler that uses a callback, not a promise. I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve, but I wouldn't do any `.close()` calls until after the event handler fires.

Comment: On the frontend I used VUE.JS and Axios to send request

Comment: @ggorlen I am getting all the reponses (network activity) from the url `await page.goto(url`  and capture `response.url().includes("api.php?id=")` that is why

Comment: oh wait lemme try

Answer (score 0):

Got it work. It was error on my side , I moved the

```
    var id = req.params.id;
    var episode = req.params.video;
    url = `www.domain2.com/${id}/${video}`;
    // console.log(object.response);
```

near the `await page.goto(url, {`